# How to authenticate Freshdesk API in Zapier webhook?

Tags: zapier, freshdesk

I'm calling the Freshdesk API to update a ticket by adding tags. I'm having trouble authenticating the call. I have encoded username and password to base64(using an external tool).

I've tried the following:

1. Basic Auth: In Zapier's BasiAuth field, I tried `username|password`
2. In the header field, I added a key Authentication with value `BasicUsername:password`

In both cases I get the error `You have to be logged in to perform this action.`

Answer (score 1):

Zapier's basic auth field should work if everything is set up correctly (and there's no `|` in your password). In that field, you should be using your actual password, not the base64 encoded pair: `david:mypass`.

If you want to do it manually, that's fine too. the `Authentication` header should be something like `Basic asdfasdf==`. Note the space between the word "basic" and the "base64" encoded `username:password`.

Comment: Hi David, I just tried Basic auth again. Getting the same error. I have contacted Freshdesk support. So far they haven't been able to figure out anything.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone looking for the solution here...

I did a header and then did this with my API token

headers
Authorization

Token token=yourapicode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[FreshDesk API - Authentication](https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#authentication)

I found this when trying to get Postman to work with their API, turns out you need to set Authorization type to Basic Auth, have your API token from FreshDesk as your username and just 'X' (without the apostrophes) as your password. Hope it helps someone else.